# I Want a User to Have Access to only One Library in my SharePoint Online Site

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-online

So I have a SharePoint site with a few different pages.

I want to add someone to that SharePoint site, but I want them to only be able to see the one library in the site and nothing else.

I know that it can be done but I'm unsure as to how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yon need to configure the libraray to have unique permission.

1. Break permission inheritance in SharePoint Online: Go to library settings-> Permissions for this document library-> click Stop Inheriting Permissions.
2. Assign unique permissions in SharePoint Online:Go to the Permissions page mentioned above, Click Grant Permissions to give user access.

For more, please refer to this article:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to that particular library ->library settings -> Permission for this library -> Break inheritance of that library(stop inheriting permissions)-> Click on Grant Permissions(here you can add that users with permission)

This is how we can add the user to the specific library.
[sample screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2GCE.png)